# Resource Recommendation - Charge interaction with electric, magnetic and light fields

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, quantum-electrodynamics, interactions

I am looking for a good book or review on the treatment of a charged particle interaction (an electron typically) with magnetic, electric and electromagnetic fields. Ideally with both classical and fully quantum treatments.